Adding pararelism to algorithm wator in java
I have a school project where they make me optimize alogrithms. The task is to add paralerism to the algorithm. I choose wator and I have to run using static decomposition of the matrix of cells with includes sharks,fish and ocean. Each thread has to take a section of the matrix as a section can be defined as a row/rows. I hav to test the algorith with different number of threads to see how the execution time changes giving more threads. The program runs through appletviewer command. I have the algorith working with only thread. It needs optimization but i do not know how. Can you help?
The program runs through putty using Xforwarding on X server with the command appletviewer wator.html
I tried using chatgpt but ended nowhere. Tried to implement forkjoinpool with number of threads in to be taken from the html script to the init method but i am facing errors with nullpointerexeptions . I tried generating a bashscript for using different number of threads to test the program but all test from the srcipt lead to the same time.
//wator.java : 
public class wator extends Applet 
implements Runnable, ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

slider sl_ncell;
slider sl_nshark;
slider sl_nfish;
slider sl_sharkbreed;
slider sl_fishbreed;
slider sl_sharkstarve;
slider sl_delay;
button bn_go;
button bn_stop;
button bn_remix;
Panel pn_tp;
Panel pn_sc;
Panel pn_bn;
panelmap pn_mp;
panelgrf pn_gf;
int nrow;
int ncol;
int ncell;
int nsizemax;
int nsize;
int nshark;
int nfish;
int delay;
boolean goflag;
boolean remixflag;
boolean brkflag;
boolean runflag;
Object mutex;
private Thread thread;
menagerie menagerie;
species ocean, fish, shark;

public void start()
{
    synchronized (mutex) {
        if (thread != null) return;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
        runflag = true;
    }
}

public void stop()
{
    runflag = false;
}

public void run()
{
    int i, j, s, f;
    
    while (runflag && (remixflag || pn_mp.paintsyncflag || brkflag || goflag)) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        if (remixflag) {
            synchronized (mutex)
                { i = nrow; j = ncol; s = nshark; f = nfish; }
            pn_mp.remix(i, j);
            if (fish.cnt != f || shark.cnt != s)
                pn_mp.remake(f, s);
            pn_mp.paintsyncflag = true;
            pn_gf.brk();
            remixflag = false;
        }
        pn_mp.paintupdate();
        if (brkflag)
            { brkflag = false; pn_gf.brk(); }
        if (goflag) {
            pn_mp.gen();
            pn_gf.gen(ncell, fish.cnt, shark.cnt);
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if (!remixflag) {
                    setnfish(fish.cnt);
                    setnshark(shark.cnt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    thread = null;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    button button;
    slider slider;
    int value;
    
    if (e.getID() != Event.ACTION_EVENT) return;
    if (e.getSource() instanceof Button) {
            button = (button) e.getSource();
            if (button == bn_go) goflag = true;
            if (button == bn_stop) goflag = false;
            if (button == bn_remix) remixflag = true;
            if (goflag || remixflag) start();
        }
    if (e.getSource() instanceof slider) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            slider = (slider) e.getSource();
            value = slider.scrollbar.value;
            if (slider == sl_ncell)
                remixflag = setsize(value);
            if (slider == sl_nshark)
                remixflag = setnshark(value);
            if (slider == sl_nfish)
                remixflag = setnfish(value);
            if (slider == sl_sharkbreed)
                brkflag = setsbreed(value);
            if (slider == sl_fishbreed)
                brkflag = setfbreed(value);
            if (slider == sl_sharkstarve)
                brkflag = setstarve(value);
            if (slider == sl_delay)
                brkflag = setdelay(value);
            if (remixflag) start();
        }
    }
}

public void init()
{
    super.init();
    menagerie = new menagerie();
    ocean = menagerie.ocean;
    fish = menagerie.fish;
    shark = menagerie.shark;
    pn_mp = new panelmap(menagerie);
    pn_mp.applet = this;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 10, 10));
    pn_tp = new Panel();
    pn_tp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 0));
    add(pn_tp);
    pn_tp.setBackground(menagerie.backgroundcolor);
    pn_sc = new Panel();
    pn_sc.setLayout(new GridLayout(16, 1, 3, 3));
    pn_tp.add("East", pn_sc);
    sl_ncell = new slider("Size", ocean.color, pn_sc, this);
    sl_nshark = new slider("Sharks", shark.color, pn_sc, this);
    sl_nfish = new slider("Fish", fish.color, pn_sc, this);
    sl_sharkbreed = new slider("Shark Breed", shark.color, pn_sc, this);
    sl_fishbreed = new slider("Fish Breed", fish.color, pn_sc, this);
    sl_sharkstarve = new slider("Shark Starve", shark.color, pn_sc, this);
    sl_delay = new slider("Delay", menagerie.foregroundcolor, pn_sc, this);
    pn_sc.add(new Label());
    pn_bn = new Panel();
    pn_bn.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3, 3, 0));
    pn_sc.add(pn_bn);
    bn_go = new button("Go", pn_bn, this);
    bn_stop = new button("Stop", pn_bn, this);
    bn_remix = new button("Remix", pn_bn, this);
    pn_tp.add("Center", pn_mp);
    pn_gf = new panelgrf();
    add(pn_gf);
    validate();
    pn_gf.init(menagerie);
    nshark = nfish = 0;
    setsize(1);
    while (ncell < 1000) setsize(nsize + 1);
    setnfish(ncell - 1);
    setnshark(1);
    sl_sharkbreed.setvalues(shark.genbreed, 1, 100);
    sl_fishbreed.setvalues(fish.genbreed, 1, 100);
    sl_sharkstarve.setvalues(shark.genstarve, 1, 100);
    sl_delay.setvalues(10, 0, 100);
    remixflag = true;
    mutex = new Object();
    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            pn_mp.resize();
            pn_gf.resize();
            remixflag = setsize();
        }
    });
    goflag = true;
}

private boolean setsize()
{
    pn_mp.getsize();
    return (setsize((int) ((long) nsize * Math.min(pn_mp.width, pn_mp.height) 
            / nsizemax)));
}

private boolean setsize(int ansize)
{
    pn_mp.getsize();
    nsizemax = Math.min(pn_mp.width, pn_mp.height);
    nsize = Math.max(1, Math.min(nsizemax, ansize));
    nrow = nsize * pn_mp.height / nsizemax;
    ncol = nsize * pn_mp.width / nsizemax;
    ncell = nrow * ncol;
    sl_ncell.scrollbar.set(nsize, 1, nsizemax);
    sl_ncell.label.set(ncell, 1, pn_mp.width * pn_mp.height);
    if (nfish + nshark > ncell) {
        nfish = (int) ((long) ncell * nfish / (nfish + nshark));
        nshark = ncell - nfish;
    }
    sl_nshark.setvalues(nshark, 0, ncell);
    sl_nfish.setvalues(nfish, 0, ncell);
    return (true);
}

private boolean setnshark(int n)
{
    nshark = Math.min(ncell, n);
    sl_nshark.setvalue(nshark);
    if (nfish + nshark > ncell)
        sl_nfish.setvalue(nfish = ncell - nshark);
    return (true);
}

private boolean setnfish(int n)
{
    nfish = Math.min(ncell, n);
    sl_nfish.setvalue(nfish);
    if (nshark + nfish > ncell)
        sl_nshark.setvalue(nshark = ncell - nfish);
    return (true);
}

private boolean setsbreed(int n)
{
    shark.genbreed = n;
    sl_sharkbreed.setvalue(n);
    return (true);
}

private boolean setfbreed(int n)
{
    fish.genbreed = n;
    sl_fishbreed.setvalue(n);
    return (true);
}

private boolean setstarve(int n)
{
    shark.genstarve = n;
    sl_sharkstarve.setvalue(n);
    return (true);
}

private boolean setdelay(int n)
{
    delay = n;
    sl_delay.setvalue(n);
    return (false);
}

} // end class wator

///wator.html:


    <html>  
    <body>  
    <applet code="wator.class" width="1024" height="768">  
    </applet>  
    </body>  
    </html>  

